# How can I rewrite page content after an exception has been thrown while rendering a view?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

As a simple example, take a page that renders to `JSP`, and has an `web.xml` `error-page` attribute as a catch all exception:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/WEB-INF/error/exceptions/throwable-layout.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Now, in the view, suppose we attempt a method that doesn't exist:

```
${requestScope.getBadVar()}
```

What happens is the output of the view terminates and the error page is then inserted immediately at the point of where the exception was thrown.

I understand this is tricky because the servlet has already started writing out the output stream and now it needs to be started from scratch, is there any way that this is possible?

Comment: Looks like a valid question. I'm  also curious to know why it was downvoted.